# Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture

Tags: c#, resources, assemblies, embedded-resource, .net-assembly

I run QBSBM project in other system it is working. But not in mine.

I saw few links in Google. For there suggestion I did few changes like changing `BuildAction` set to `Embedded resource` and resource file. And `Access Modifier` is also set to `Public` (double click the `.resx` file to open the file and the `Access Modifier` is located along the top of the editor window).

Could not find any  resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. 
Make sure `Manufacturing.Images.resources` was correctly embedded or linked into assembly `QBSBM` at compile time. Or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

Can any one give me suggestion how can i solve this error...

Comment: Have you set your [`AssemblyCultureAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblycultureattribute.aspx) to specify which culture is embedded in your main assembly?

Comment: I set <Assembly: AssemblyCulture("")> for main assembly. I run the assembly.i am getting same error message.

Comment: Can any one give me suggestion how can i solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You shoud change your resource build action. In order to do that, on the solution explorer, go to the resource property pane and change the Build Action from content to Embedded Resource.